# Fill multiple textboxes after selecting from a DropDownList in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a DropDownList that is linked to a SQL database. It currently shows a list of customers. I am trying to make it so that once a customer is selected, multiple textboxes are automatically filled (such as address, city, etc). I am able to automatically fill the "company name" textbox as the value is the one selected, but I do not know how to fill the other textboxes using the rest of the data in the row. How would I best go about doing this?

in .aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

C#:

```
DataTable customers = new DataTable();
...

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CustomerName FROM Customers.dbo.Customer", connection);
                adapter.Fill(customers);
                DropDownList1.DataSource = customers;
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "CustomerName";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "CustomerName";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

EDIT: Thanks Karl for your help. Follow his advice if you have a similar issue. Also, make sure to change the dropdownlist so it looks like:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="CompanyChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

EDIT2: For those that are having the same problem.. Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)

    {
        LoadOptions();
    }
}
protected void LoadOptions()
    {
        DataTable customers = new DataTable();

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(INSERT YOUR CONNECTION STRING HERE);
        using (connection)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Column1 FROM Table", connection);

            adapter.Fill(customers);
            DropDownListID.DataSource = customers;

            companyselect.DataTextField = "Column1";
            companyselect.DataValueField = "Column1";
            companyselect.DataBind(); 
        }
    }

protected void SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selected= DropDownListID.SelectedItem.Value;

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(YOUR CONNECTION STRING);
        using (connection)
        {

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column1= @Column1", connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column1", selected);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            using (reader)
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    reader.Read();

//add as many as needed to fill your textboxes
                    TextBox1.Text = reader.GetString(1);
                    TextBox2.Text = reader.GetString(2);
                    TextBox3.Text = reader.GetString(3);
                }
                else { }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is what my dropdownlist looks like:

```
<asp:DropDownList  ID="DropDownListID" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="SelectionChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Posting your code is a good first step.

Comment: @KarlAnderson I added my code. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: IMHO the best way to do it is to make one call to the db like you are doing. Once one  has been selected. Do another call to get the details. This way if you have 1000 customers you are not pulling down 10,000 rows (10 fields)

Comment: Do you have an identity column in the database?

Comment: @logixologist Yes, each customer in the database has an ID. How do I make another call to the db for the rest of the details once an option has been selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend that you use the `CustomerID` or equivalent ID field in the database as the `DataValueField` in your drop down list, as you may want to allow the same customer name in the database, but be able to tell them apart by ID.

Instead, try this:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CustomerName, CustomerID FROM Customers.dbo.Customer", connection);
adapter.Fill(customers);
DropDownList1.DataSource = customers;
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "CustomerName";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "CustomerID";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

> Note: Change `CustomerID` to whatever the actual ID column name in your database table actually is.

Now in your drop down list's `SelectedIndexChanged` event, grab the ID of the selected item and query the database for the single row of data, like this:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedID = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;

    SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers.dbo.Customer WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID", connection);
    theCommand.Paramters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", selectedId);
    theCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    using (SqlDataReader theReader = theCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (theReader.HasRows)
        {
            // Get the first row
            theReader.Read();

            // Set the text box values
            CustomerName.Text = theReader.GetString(0);
            ...
        }
    } 
}
```

> Note: The retrieval of the single row of customer data uses a parameterized query to avoid SQL Injection vulnerabilities. Also, the code above uses the `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` along with `using` blocks to properly dispose of the reader object.

Comment: This seems to work somewhat, but the selectedID returned is always 0. Once an option is selected, a textbox with the CustomerID shows 0 and the DropDownList resets. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Found the issue! I was refreshing the options of the ddl every time an option was selected. It should look like Page_Load(..){ if(!IsPostBack) {LoadOptions();} }. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @teabos - no problem, glad it is working for you. Feel free to up-vote the answer when you can. :-)

Comment: Thanks Karl, Great answer so I +1'd it for you. I had to jump into a meeting so I couldnt finish answering his question ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SQLconn.Open();

            string req = "select distinct CapaciteTotal from Avion where NomAvion=" + DropDownList1.Text + "";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(req, SQLconn);
            SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                TextBox1.Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                if (DropDownList4.Text == "Aller Retour")
                {
                    TextBox2.Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                }

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('Probleme de la base de donnee : " + ex.Message + "')</script>");
        }
        finally
        {
            SQLconn.Close();
        }

    }
```